# Making Gif Files animation only after mouse over or clicking on them (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, gif

on winform - C#:
how do i change a gif file to start its animation after you click it, or after you stand on it with the mouse?
best regards!

Comment: You couldhave an image of the first frame of the gif and change it to the gif when click or hover event is launched

Comment: @Aimnox A good sleight-of-hand approach.  Old-school web thinking ;)

Comment: hi, thank you! can you help me with the code (i am not c# expert) how do i exchange the picture on click from the png to the gif + delay 2 sec + change other tab after that?

Comment: http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_animated_gif.php